# Equivalent to Excel Slicers for Web Applications?

Tags: javascript, excel, web, data-visualization, crossfilter

**Is there an equivalent of Excel's slicers for Web applications?**

**Context...** This is meant to be used in a web dashboard.

**Some background for anyone not familiar with Excel slicers...** Excel slicers allow you to quickly make a list of filters connected to your data source by simply selecting the desired field. In Excel, slicers are tied with pivot tables and charts to create powerful and interactive reports. Slicers can also connect with other slicers and give visual feedback on which items do not have data for a given selection ([see image here](http://pakaccountants.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/sd-10.gif) showing various slicers around a chart - the greyed buttons do not have any data - this is known as cross-filtering).

**Found so far...** The closest thing I have found is CrossFilter.js and DC.js which work with the D3 charting library. However, development on Crossfilter and DC seemed to have stopped. I'm new to web development, so if there is a simple solution to this and I'm digging to deep - let me know!

**Thank you for any help!!**

Comment: filtering in html with javascript is very common. Approach is dependent on data structure, usage and filtering needs. As it stands question is far too broad without more specific usage information

Comment: Thanks for answering charlietfl. I agree it is a broad question (intentionally). I'm just looking for an easy way to do this. Lets assume the data source is normalized data in Json format from a Web API. The data is the equivalent to 10,000 rows and 30 fields. I'd like to make a dashboard view (like in the image shown in the question) with charts and tables all connected by some buttons that filter the data. In excel it is super easy to do (with pivot tables, pivot charts, and slicers), I'm just looking for the best process for this type of application.

Comment: Would be fairly easy to wire up in an angular.js or backbone.js or react.js app

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl. I was hoping it would be easy! Would you know of any tutorials for this sort of thing? I've been searching to no avail. The goal is to have a couple charts and tables connected to a few sets of filters. Its such a common thing in excel, I thought there would be something.

Comment: html and javascript are not excel. You will have to use javascript charting libraries and your own filtering

Comment: filtering may be so common in html and javascript. But, there is so far nothing that I came across that can match an excel slicer's behaviour perfectly. Excel slicer's behaviour is the "ideal" UI to filter a table in a flash! and further drill down on multiple columns. one may not believe me, that only shows lack of experiences with UI design. So, it will be interesting if someone can point to a link or library with a demo to show table filtering using slicer like behaviour in javascript/html. please do not comment generic statements like it is so common etc. prove it with a link and a demo.